# apachectl/httpd: recover config file that's currently running?

Tags: apache, config

Apache is running but I lost my httpd.config file, because I did something a little careless.

Is there any way to dump the settings of a running Apache instance?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have backup of httpd.conf file then you can recover delete file using testdisk utility. Please refer to below link.

[Recover deleted file in Linux](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download)